# Having an issue getting TKinter to track mouse movement to an object

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, mouseevent

I was unsure whether to post the full code or not, but here's what I have:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 800

MID_X = WIDTH/2
MID_Y = HEIGHT/2

SHIP_R = 15
SHIP_SPD = 10

bub_id = list()
bub_r = list()
bub_speed = list()

MIN_BUB_R = 10
MAX_BUB_R = 30
MAX_BUB_SPD = 6

GAP = 100

window = Tk()
window.title('Bubble Blaster')

c = Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg='darkblue')
c.pack()

ship_id = c.create_polygon(5, 5, 5, 25, 30, 15, fill='red')
ship_id2 = c.create_oval(0, 0, 30, 30, outline='red')

c.move(ship_id, MID_X, MID_Y)
c.move(ship_id2, MID_X, MID_Y)



def move_ship(event):
    fixed = True
    while fixed == True:
        ship_x, ship_y = event.x, event.y
        c.move(ship_id, ship_x, ship_y)
        c.move(ship_id2, ship_x, ship_y)
        sleep(0.01)



def create_bubble():
    x = WIDTH + GAP
    y = randint(0, HEIGHT)
    r = randint(MIN_BUB_R, MAX_BUB_R)
    id1 = c.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, outline='white')
    bub_id.append(id1)
    bub_r.append(r)
    bub_speed.append(randint(1, MAX_BUB_SPD))

def move_bubbles():
    for i in range(len(bub_id)):
        c.move(bub_id[i], -bub_speed[i], 0)

def get_coords(id_num):
    pos = c.coords(id_num)
    x = (pos[0] + pos[2])/2
    y = (pos[1] + pos[3])/2
    return x, y

def del_bubble(i):
    del bub_r[i]
    del bub_speed[i]
    c.delete(bub_id[i])
    del bub_id[i]

def clean_up_bubs():
    for i in range(len(bub_id)-1, -1, -1):
        x, y = get_coords(bub_id[i])
        if x < -GAP:
            del_bubble(i)

from math import sqrt

def distance(id1, id2):
    x1, y1 = get_coords(id1)
    x2, y2 = get_coords(id2)
    return sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)

def collision():
    points = 0
    for bub in range(len(bub_id)-1, -1, -1):
        if distance(ship_id2, bub_id[bub]) < (SHIP_R+bub_r[bub]):
            points += (bub_r[bub] + bub_speed[bub])
            del_bubble(bub)
    return points

c.create_text(50, 30, text='TIME', fill='white')
c.create_text(150, 30, text='SCORE', fill='white')

time_text = c.create_text(50, 50, fill='white')
score_text = c.create_text (150, 50, fill='white')

def show_score(score):
    c.itemconfig(score_text, text=str(score))

def show_time(time_left):
    c.itemconfig(time_text, text=str(time_left))

from time import sleep, time
BUB_CHANCE = 20
TIME_LIMIT = 30
BONUS_SCORE = 1000

# MAIN GAME LOOP
c.bind("<B1_Motion>", move_ship)
score = 0
bonus = 0
end = time() + TIME_LIMIT

while time() < end:
    if randint(1, BUB_CHANCE) == 1:
        create_bubble()
    move_bubbles()
    move_ship("<B1_Motion>")
    clean_up_bubs()
    score += collision()
    if (int(score / BONUS_SCORE)) > bonus:
        bonus += 1
        end += TIME_LIMIT
    show_score(score)
    show_time(int(end-time()))
    window.update()
    sleep(0.01)

c.create_text(MID_X, MID_Y, \
    text='PARTY TIME, EXCELLENT', fil='white', font=('Helvetica', 30))
c.create_text(MID_X, MID_Y + 30, \
    text='Score: ' + str(score), fill='white')
c.create_text(MID_X, MID_Y + 45, \
    text='BONU TIME: ' + str(bonus*TIME_LIMIT), fill='white')
```

I'm a complete beginner when it comes to python, and have been given an assignment to only use tkinter and the standard libraries to give mouse movement to this "game". I just can't seem to get the right grasp of it. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to remove your while loop, and put most of your functionality into a function. Put everything you want to do in a single frame of animation into this function.

Next, call this function on a regular interval using the `after` command. This allows the event loop to run continuously, which is important for your UI to be responsive. You can do your `time() < end` calculation inside this function, and use the result to break the cycle once time is up.

It looks something like this:

```
def draw_one_frame():
    if randint(1, BUB_CHANCE) == 1:
        create_bubble()
    move_bubbles()
    # move_ship("<B1_Motion>")
    clean_up_bubs()
    score += collision()
    if (int(score / BONUS_SCORE)) > bonus:
        bonus += 1
        end += TIME_LIMIT
    show_score(score)
    show_time(int(end-time()))

    if time() < end:
        after(10, draw_one_frame)
```

You can use the first parameter to `after` to control how many frames per second you wish your program to run at.

Next, you need to handle mouse movement. You do this by creating a binding to the movement of the mouse.  You do this *outside* of the `draw_one_frame` method. It looks something like this:

```
c.bind("<B1-Motion>", move_ship)
```

You also need to remove the infinite loop from `move_ship`, and also remove the sleep. You simply need to do all the calculations for the current mouse position. The function will be already be looping -- being called once each time the mouse moves.

Finally, you need to call `window.mainloop()` after all your other code, so that the program can process events. This should be the very last line of your program. It will run until the window is destroyed.